# Why is primusrun slower than optirun

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm having a similar issue to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321182/why-is-primusrun-slower-than-optirun), only primusrun is still slower even with vblank synchronization disabled.

EDIT: I didn't run standard glxspheres without turning off vblank sychronization. When I do I get

```
$ vblank_mode=0 glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
139.729257 frames/sec - 155.937850 Mpixels/sec
201.142942 frames/sec - 224.475523 Mpixels/sec

$ glxspheres64 
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
60.409773 frames/sec - 67.417306 Mpixels/sec

$ optirun glxspheres64 
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2
276.092868 frames/sec - 308.119641 Mpixels/sec

erik@yorda:~$ vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxspheres64 
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Polygons in scene: 62464
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
198.399436 frames/sec - 221.413770 Mpixels/sec
```

I'm not sure why primus would be running slower. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with the experimental 310 drivers.

EDIT: It seems that primusrun is giving no performance boost over the onboard intel graphics.

Answer (score 0):

There's a texture upload speed regression in Mesa 9.2, which is what Ubuntu 13.10 ships with.  You can try installing Mesa git packages from oibaf ppa or xorg-edgers ppa, and then try `PRIMUS_UPLOAD=2 primusrun` (setting PRIMUS_UPLOAD=2 explicitely may be necessary to workaround a regression in mesa git that was fixed only recently).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by texture upload speed regression. I using the xorg edgers ppa. When I tried setting `PRIMUS_UPLOAD=2` the frame rate went down to 40.